# AFNetworking 2.0 - How to download uiimage async

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

In ios using AFNetworking 2.0 how can I easily download a remote image asynchronously and cache it for future request of the same url? I'm looking for a convenient way to receive both error callbacks and successful ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

also mentioned [How to download image with AFNetworking 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501652/how-to-download-image-with-afnetworking-2-0/19502211#19502211)

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperation doesn't have a member called responseSerializer. Should use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead.

Comment: I have used both 2.0 and 2.4.1 and none of them seem to have this property.

Comment: @AndyIbanez not sure what is going on with your project then. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide look under __Serialization__

Comment: It must have have something to do with the fact I added the project from CocoaPods. I guess I will just try to download it directly from GitHub.

Comment: @AndyIbanez make sure you have the correct `#import`