# How to download image with AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, afnetworking-2

Appareantly there is no `AFImageRequestOperation`, but only `AFImageResponseSerializer` and frankly I don't get it or maybe I'm just looking too long through AFNetworking site... Downloading images with previous AFNetworking was like a charm. I'd hate to go back to older AFnetworking, since I did almost all stuff via the new version... Anyone?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

SO you want something like this for 2.0.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

As mentioned by Adam you can also do something like the below if you are just wanting to throw it into an imageView

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sitewithimage.com/images/myimage.png"]];
```

Comment: Would this be on the main queue or the background queue?

Comment: @Tander The completion blocks run on the main queue

Comment: This answer's great and all, but check out https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h, a lot of donkey work done for you if you're just putting an image in an image view

Comment: @AdamWaite thanks, I updated my answer with a generic version, however if someone would like to use placeholders and such you can look at all the options in the link

Comment: Bot's answer that the completion block is correct, though simplifying just a little. There's a `completionQueue` property on **AFURLConnectionOperation** that you can use to specify the queue used. The default is the main queue. :)

Answer (score 4):

for old version, there is no responseSerializer, you can also

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
//requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using `AFNetworking` in Swift, [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501652/how-to-download-image-with-afnetworking-2-0/19502211#19502211) can be written as below

```
    let requestOperation : AFHTTPRequestOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: urlRequest)
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = AFImageResponseSerializer()

    requestOperation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (requestOperation, responseObject) in
       print(responseObject)
        _imageView.image = responseObject as? UIImage

    }) { (requestOperation, error) in
       print(error)
    }
    requestOperation.start()
```