# Loading imageviews with AFNetworking via JSON hierarchy and objectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

Very new to `AFNetworking`, but after many SO questions... I've concluded that this is the solution to my issue.

I've got a hierarchy of `JSON` data loading my TableViewController cells dynamically. All of my text strings are loading appropriately but the image from my `URL` is not making it to my imageview.

Before utilizing the `AFNetworking` library, I had the images loaded, but I was experiencing some issues with the photos not staying loaded when I scrolled away and returned (they had to load again.)

What am I missing to get my images in there?

**TableViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
    siderbarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    siderbarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

    // Set the gesture
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_app_white.png"]];

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [tableView reloadData]; // if tableView is unidentified make the tableView IBOutlet
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return jsonArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NeedCardTableViewCell *cell = (NeedCardTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"needCard"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NeedCardTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"needCard"];
    }

    NSDictionary *needs = jsonArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"userImage" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        _imageProfPic.image = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage to figure this one out with the use of this tutorial: 
[Networking Made Easy with AFNetworking](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-made-easy-with-afnetworking--mobile-10741)

I used the final snippet of code to get my desired result:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[movie objectForKey:@"artworkUrl100"]];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

I cut the second line of his code because I already have an if statement in my `PHP`/`JSON`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NeedCardTableViewCell *cell = (NeedCardTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"needCard"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NeedCardTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"needCard"];
    }

    NSDictionary *needs = jsonArray[indexPath.row]; // get the data dict for the row
    cell.textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
    cell.textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
    cell.textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[needs objectForKey:@"userImage"]];
    [cell.imageProfPic setImageWithURL:url];

    return cell;
}
```

It worked like a charm, and the tutorial was pretty helpful since I'm a rookie with `AFNetworking`.

Comment: In your original question, it is was not clear that you were getting the URL from the key of a dictionary via `@"userImage"` since the statement `[manager GET:@"userImage"` would be using `userImage` as a URL. Glad it worked out in the end either way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [AFNetworking+UIImageView](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) category? You can then call:

```
[_imageProfPic setImage:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myimageurl.com/imagename.jpg"]];
```

This will make a request and then set the returned image to your UIImageView's UIImage without you having to do anything else. You should also consider initializing NSURLCache in your AppDelegate:

```
NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                  diskCapacity:10 * 1024 * 1024
                                                      diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
```

Take a look at [NSHipster's run down on NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/). This will help reload images, and all your requests, much faster the second time around. This is increasingly important when dealing with images and tables.

Comment: how would I make that afnetworking+uiimageview request using my key from the jsonArray? Also, I'm assuming I just import the afnetworking+uiimageview.h file for this?

Comment: If you are using AFNetworking, I assume you would like to make a request to obtain data from outside of your application, such as from an API. In this case, you must set the URL of the image you want in the setImage method. For instance, placing `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Internet1.jpg` will return an image from Wikipedia's site and set it as the UIImage of your UIImageView. What does `@"userImage"` represent in your GET request? And yes, you would just import the category to use it.

Comment: @"userImage" is a key from my JSON file. It is being saved into "jsonArray" and it's value is an image's URL (dependent on what user's info is being requested). I'm using objectForKey to call the image's URL out of jsonArray to place into my image view "imageProfPic". I'm using AFNetworking to make my URL (otherwise a string) into an image that can fill an imageview.

Comment: Basically my URL is always different. So, I have the URL saved in "jsonArray" under the key "userImage" for when I'm ready to call it.