# AFNetworking and downloading images

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to know is there way to download images with my code one by one ? Now async

```
    NSString *urlString = link;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        completion(operation, responseObject, nil);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [RequestAPI sharedInstance].downloadsCount -= 1;
        DDLogError(@"FAIL download image: %@",error);
    }];

    [requestOperation start];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501652/how-to-download-image-with-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: have u tried accomplishing it via global queues???

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

1. Create a `NSObject` class for downloading the images. Lets call this `DownloadImages`. The class has an array of images to be downloaded `arrayOfImagesURL`.
2. Create a delegate for the class `DownloadImages` to make a call back when you finish downloading an image. View how to this in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c).
3. Implement `AFNetworking` as you like, you can also accomplish this by using the iOS 7 API `NSURLSession`. So in the completion block of your download task, you need to do 2 things:

   1. Continue downloading the next URL in `arrayOfImagesURL`.
   2. Do a call back with the delegate to the parent controller for processing.

Tell me if there's something need to be more clarify.