# setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure No block is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to get an image asynchronously from an url with AFNetworking 2.0

My problem is that neither success nor failure are called

I've checked my URL in a browser so the problem is not here

```
UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imgv setImageWithURLRequest:myURL
            placeholderImage:nil
                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                        /*some code*/
                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                        /*some code*/       
];
```

When I look deeper inside `setImageWithUrlRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure`

```
   __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    self.af_imageRequestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    self.af_imageRequestOperation.responseSerializer = self.imageResponseSerializer;
    [self.af_imageRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if ([[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation.request URL]]) {
            if (success) {
                success(urlRequest, operation.response, responseObject);
            } else if (responseObject) {
                strongSelf.image = responseObject;
            }

            if (operation == strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation){
                    strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation = nil;
            }
        }

        [[[strongSelf class] sharedImageCache] cacheImage:responseObject forRequest:urlRequest];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if ([[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation.request URL]]) {
            if (failure) {
                failure(urlRequest, operation.response, error);
            }

            if (operation == strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation){
                    strongSelf.af_imageRequestOperation = nil;
            }
        }
    }];
```

My code goes trought `[self.af_imageRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {`
 with success but i've noticed that `__strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;` are both `nil`

Any idea?

Comment: You need to hold onto a strong reference to `imgv` to prevent it being `dealloced`. What else do you do with it other than instantiating it and calling `setImageWithUrlRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure` on it?

Comment: When I was using afnetworking 1.xx I was doing this  `[imgv setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {  }]  but i can't do this anymore in Afnetworking 2.0, maybe it's why it's not working anymore ? So i'm not doing anything else now

Comment: Maybe you should try adding the `imgv` to your view hierarchy and thus hold a strong reference to it so that it doesn't get dealloced...

Comment: I don't use the imageView for anything else than downloading the picture, as soon as I have the picture I save it to an other place. I'm trying to find a replacement for setDownloadProgressBlock in afnetworking 2.0 ...

Comment: Maybe look at `downloadTaskWithRequest:progress:destination:completionHandler:`

Comment: I finally used this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501652/how-to-download-image-with-afnetworking-2-0     Thanks for helping me anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Your imgv is never retained so it will be released after current scope so in your block weakSelf will be release when image is successfuly downloaded so thats why you are getting nil.

Comment: For me, I was initializing the image view in a method, and the method ended before the block returned, so obviously the image view had been deallocated.  I fixed it by making the image view a class level variable