# Reusing an UIImage object in an UIImageView that is retrieved with "setImageWithURL"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, afnetworking

I have tableview that consists of cells of Youtube thumbnails that is retrieved with the help of AFNetworking's setImageWithURL method. So how do I re-use the thumbnails in these cells to another view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UIImageView+AFNetworking` ,once `image` `downloaded` with a `url` gets `cached` using `AFImageCache` (NSCache).

Trick here is use `same url` to `download` `image` but it will `not` opt for `download` but provide you `cached` `image`.

**EDIT** : 
Take a look at this in `UIImageView+AFNetworking's setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`

```
UIImage *cachedImage = [[[self class] sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:urlRequest];
if (cachedImage) 
{
  //provide cache image

} 
else 
{
  //download new image from url

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. I will upvote and check this as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference the image instance from the `UIImageView`.

```
UIImage *imageToReuse = cell.imageView.image
```

Have a look at the [UIImagView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html) documentation.

A better option though would be to use AFNetworking to download the images, put them in a cache, for example using [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/index.html), and then getting them through it. This seems like a cleaner approach to me then extracting them from the cell. These links might be useful in this regard:

- https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking#consuming-json-xml-images-and-property-lists
- [How to download image with AFNetworking 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501652/how-to-download-image-with-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: Well, yeah. I did use AFNetworking in the project. It's just that I forgot to highlight it with code tags in my original question so you probably missed it. My bad. The question is, won't I get a different reference of image than the one retrieved from the net if I use your code above?