# dispatch_async for getting many images from url

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I want to get many images from diffrent url and set it like image's buttons .
I was trying to do this like it's showing above but nothing is happen . When i access this view controller it doesn't have any image for buttons and also neither the banner view is not showed...        .

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [pictureUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
                img2.image = img1;
                [bt setBackgroundImage:img2.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  });
});
```

Comment: Try changing `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];` to the following lines, to check for errors- `NSError *error;` `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];` `if(error) { NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); }`

Comment: @AMI289 I agreed to your comment..

Comment: @Sarat_Patel maybe try adding it to your answer mate. It seems that Georgiana 'decides' to ignore my comments.....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a library that supports cache for images. For instance, I used [AFNetworking](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for one of my projects and it is awesome. And it automatically handles in background for you. In my case I needed a library that automatically cancels a request when I start new one and it worked for me. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/s/5Artists/blob/master/5Artists/Classes/Home/TWLHomeViewController.m#L330). And you can see similiar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502274/1772101) from another thread as follows:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should use **`async` and `sync` pairs**, the inner block should be synchromous to the first one so it will take image when the data is downloaded and available. Also, don;t forget to handle errors:

Try like this:

```
// Show HUD here
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
{

      NSError* error;
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [pictureUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
      NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        if(!error && data)
        {
            UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            img2.image = img1;
            [bt setBackgroundImage:img2.image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
             /*
                //----OR----
               [bt setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
              */           
        }
        else
        {
            // Do error handling here
        }
        // Hide HUD here
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: the same problem . data is nill

Comment: Did you check the `url` ? Is it valid ? Also did you do an NSLog to `error.description` ?

Comment: What did you get when you hit the url in browser? An image ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:yourDefaultImgUrl];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourImageUrl];      
        if (imageData){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{               
                 imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this modification,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [pictureUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
       NSError *error;
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];   
       if(error)
        {
           NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
          UIImage *img1 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
          [bt setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
       // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //img2.image = img1;
       // });
});
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
                NSString *ImageURL = @"yourURL.jpg";
                NSData *imageData;
                if (ImageURL == nil || ImageURL == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
                {
                }

                else
                {
                    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if (ImageURL == nil || ImageURL == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
                    {
                        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame_noimage.png"];
                    }
                    else if (imageData == nil || imageData == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageData] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageData] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
                    {
                        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame_noimage.png"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    }
                });

            });
```